# Norco Threshold Carbon SL 2017

Tags: compatibility

I have a pair of Mavic XA Pro 650b’s that I am trying to fit into my Norco Threshold Carbon SL 2017 is there an obvious reason that the rear wheel fouls the disc mount boss? Am I able to rectify the issue?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you please attach an image of what you see is happening with the disc/mount interference? It should be easier to decide what is wrong by looking at the picture.

Comment: Whats the axle and frame spacing - Are the wheels Boost?

Comment: From googling it comes with Donnelly Crusade MXP, 700x33c, Tubeless Ready, Folding tyres, so the standard rims are 700c.   You're obviously fitting a different wheel, so this might be a minor inference issue?  Perhaps a different rear hub/wheel will clear better.

Comment: @mattnz  Spec site says "Norco Threshold, Carbon, 12x142mm TA Dropouts" and rear hub is listed as "DT Swiss 350, 28 Hole, 12x142mm"  but that is the stock wheel.  No idea what hub OP has but rim is a Mavic as per question.

Comment: @Criggie a quick Google search shows it's a complete wheel that comes in both Boost and non-Boost versions. Mavic has been selling complete wheels since the 90s, so it doesn't make much sense to assume the brand always refers to rim only.

Comment: All sorted now and fitted to my Norco Threshold SL. The issue was wrong adapter fitted to rear wheel. Thank you all for the support 